# Pandas group by two column with swapped values in other 4 columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-itertools

I have a large Pandas DataFrame with many  columns. I would like to make sure that Column C and Column E contains value in same order.

For example: If `first two rows shows (red and green) & third row shows (Green and red)` then `third row should change it to red and green` as shown below.

Input

[image]

Output

[image]

Additional task :

While making this change I would like to swap the value of other four columns (2 pairs) in same row.

Input

[image]

Output

[image]

Note : When we apply group by it also includes below highlighted row but I don’t want to swap the values because it has a standard sequence red first and green second.

[image]

I have tried it with below function but after few 100 entries, it is difficult to track all combinations manually. File size is huge and has many rows and columns.

```
def swap(x):
    if x[0] < 0:
        return [x[1],x[0]]
    else:
        return [x[0],x[1]]
```

Is there some way to swap multiple values in given condition?

**EDIT 1 : after Rob Raymond‘s answer**

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import random

df = pd.read_excel("Path\\test_copy.xlsx") # My original excel sheet which contains all data  

colors1 = []
colors2 = []
colors = []
colors1 = df['C'].values.tolist()
colors2 = df['E'].values.tolist()
colors = colors1 + colors2
colors = list( dict.fromkeys(colors) )
colorp = list(itertools.permutations(colors, 2))

df1 = pd.DataFrame([pd.Series(colorp[random.randint(0,len(colorp)-1)]).rename({0:"C",1:"E"}).to_dict() for i in range(20)])

# find rows where colors in different order to a previous combination
df2 = df.assign(swap=df.apply(lambda r: ((df.loc[(df.C.eq(r.E)&df.E.eq(r.C))].index.values)<r.name).any(), axis=1))

# swap the columns, can be extended to other columns
df2.loc[df2.swap] = df2.loc[df2.swap].rename(columns={"C":"E","E":"C"})
df2.loc[df2.swap] = df2.loc[df2.swap].rename(columns={"M":"N","M":"N"})
df2.loc[df2.swap] = df2.loc[df2.swap].rename(columns={"G":"I","I":"G"})


# lets compare what's happened...
df2.join(df, rsuffix="_start")

df2.to_excel (r"PAth\\result_swapped.xlsx", index = None, header=True)
```

Values are getting swapped in all six columns at a same time as expected but result is not accurate. Output file still contains some values in “C” and “E” columns in `opposite sequence`. And for those `wrong sequence` rows swap status is `“TRUE”`. That means the original sequence was correct but our script has swapped it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Simulating your data
- simulating condition - where an earlier row exists with columns in opposite order
- swap columns is done using a **mask** and a `rename()`

```
import itertools
colors = ["Red","Green","Blue","Purple","Indigo","Pink"]

colorp = list(itertools.permutations(colors, 2))

df = pd.DataFrame([pd.Series(colorp[random.randint(0,len(colorp)-1)]).rename({0:"C",1:"E"}).to_dict() for i in range(20)])

# find rows where colors in different order to a previous combination
df2 = df.assign(swap=df.apply(lambda r: ((df.loc[(df.C.eq(r.E)&df.E.eq(r.C))].index.values)<r.name).any(), axis=1))

# swap the columns, can be extended to other columns
df2.loc[df2.swap] = df2.loc[df2.swap].rename(columns={"C":"E","E":"C"})

# lets compare what's happened...
df2.join(df, rsuffix="_start")
```

|  | C | E | swap | C_start | E_start |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Green | Indigo | False | Green | Indigo |
| 1 | Pink | Red | False | Pink | Red |
| 2 | Indigo | Blue | False | Indigo | Blue |
| 3 | Green | Blue | False | Green | Blue |
| 4 | Green | Indigo | True | Indigo | Green |
| 5 | Indigo | Blue | True | Blue | Indigo |
| 6 | Pink | Purple | False | Pink | Purple |
| 7 | Indigo | Blue | True | Blue | Indigo |
| 8 | Green | Pink | False | Green | Pink |
| 9 | Red | Blue | False | Red | Blue |
| 10 | Red | Indigo | False | Red | Indigo |
| 11 | Red | Purple | False | Red | Purple |
| 12 | Green | Indigo | True | Indigo | Green |
| 13 | Pink | Purple | True | Purple | Pink |
| 14 | Green | Indigo | True | Indigo | Green |
| 15 | Purple | Indigo | False | Purple | Indigo |
| 16 | Indigo | Blue | True | Blue | Indigo |
| 17 | Green | Blue | False | Green | Blue |
| 18 | Red | Green | False | Red | Green |
| 19 | Indigo | Green | True | Green | Indigo |

Comment: thanks for sharing the useful information. You deserves an upvote. I have created the lists “colors” &  “colorp” as per your guideline. I have tried the solution but the issue is not resolved 100%,

Comment: **colors** and **colorp** are not part of the solution,  just used to build a sample dataframe as there is no data in your question that can be used in a re-producable example.  From what I can see *wrong* order is fact you have not defined correct order... this solution just uses what is seen first,  not a definition of correct

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I have used my data-frame and applied as mentioned in your script and it is working fine.